# Combining the second element of a tuple into a list based on the first element

Tags: haskell

I've been working on trying to get a list of strings together based on the first element in my tuple.

```
Ex: 
[('a', "Hello"),('b', "Goodbye"), ('a', "World"), ('b', "World")] 
-> 
[('a', ["Hello","World"]),('b',["Goodbye","World"])]
```

I've think I've gotten pretty close, but I'm not getting the correct output.

```
map (foo . unzip) . groupBy (\st en -> fst st == fst en) . sort 
     where edge (name, futureList) = (head name, futureList)
```

I'm guessing that it has something to do with the futureList at the end. I think that there needs to be a function attached to it.

Comment: Using [`Data.MultiMap`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/multimap-1.2.1/docs/Data-MultiMap.html) you could do `assocs . fromList`

Comment: Even with just `Data.Map`, you could use `assocs . (unionsWith (++)) . map (\(x,y) -> M.singleton x [y])`

Comment: `assocs . fromListWith (++) . (map . fmap) (:[])`

Answer (score 4):

I didn't understand what you were trying to do in your code, so I had to build up to it myself.  Here's how I approached it: We'll put our starting list in `x` to make testing simple:

```
> x = [('a', "Hello"),('b', "Goodbye"), ('a', "World"), ('b', "World")]
```

and then import the `groupBy` function:

```
Prelude> import Data.List
Prelude Data.List> :t groupBy
groupBy :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [[a]]
```

So we can start with grouping by the first element of the tuple:

```
> groupBy (\x y -> fst x == fst y) x
[[('a',"Hello")],[('b',"Goodbye")],[('a',"World")],[('b',"World")]]
```

Ah, but that didn't work because the matching elements aren't next to each other, so we need a `sort`:

```
> groupBy (\x y -> fst x == fst y) $ sort x
[[('a',"Hello"),('a',"World")],[('b',"Goodbye"),('b',"World")]]
```

There is another nice function that lets us make this more succinct, `on`:

```
Prelude Data.List> import Data.Function
Prelude Data.List Data.Function> :t on
on :: (b -> b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> a -> c
```

Which lets us do this:

```
> groupBy ((==) `on` fst) $ sort x
[[('a',"Hello"),('a',"World")],[('b',"Goodbye"),('b',"World")]]
```

The lists we want are just the second halves of those tuples:

```
> map (snd) $ map unzip $ groupBy ((==) `on` fst) $ sort x
[["Hello","World"],["Goodbye","World"]]
```

And the letters are the first halves -- they're all grouped, so we can just take the `head` of them:

```
> map (head . fst) $ map unzip $ groupBy ((==) `on` fst) $ sort x
"ab"
```

(read that result as `['a', 'b']` -- a string is just a list of characters.)  Now we're very close, and it seems like there ought to be a way to compose the `(,)` function (tuple construction) with our two `head . fst` and `snd` functions.  But I haven't come up with that yet.

Instead, inspired by [@karakfa's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47804730/47552), I made use of a helper:

```
> mapFst f (a, b) = (f a, b)
> :t mapFst
mapFst :: (t2 -> t1) -> (t2, t) -> (t1, t)
```

To arrive at:

```
> map (mapFst head) $ map unzip $ groupBy ((==) `on` fst) $ sort x
[('a',["Hello","World"]),('b',["Goodbye","World"])]
```

Swapping out `.` for `$` yields an actual function w/o explicit reference to our `x` test value:

```
> (map (mapFst head) . map unzip . groupBy ((==) `on` fst) . sort) x
[('a',["Hello","World"]),('b',["Goodbye","World"])]
```

And finally, two `map` composed together can be collapsed:

```
> (map (mapFst head . unzip) . groupBy ((==) `on` fst) . sort) x
[('a',["Hello","World"]),('b',["Goodbye","World"])]
```

And its type is as we'd expect:

```
> :t (map (mapFst head . unzip) . groupBy ((==) `on` fst) . sort)
(map (mapFst head . unzip) . groupBy ((==) `on` fst) . sort)
  :: (Ord b, Ord t1) => [(t1, b)] -> [(t1, [b])]
```

Answer (score 2):

you have name mix-up (foo vs edge)

essentially the same code

```
import Data.List(sort,groupBy)
import Data.Function(on)

map (mapFst head . unzip) . groupBy ((==) `on` fst) . sort 
    where mapFst f (a, b) = (f a, b)
```

gives

```
[('a',["Hello","World"]),('b',["Goodbye","World"])]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [`fromListWith`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.10.2/docs/Data-IntMap-Strict.html#v:fromListWith) from [`Data.Map.Strict`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.10.2/docs/Data-IntMap-Strict.html) to do this:

```
import Data.Map.Strict (fromListWith, toList)
import Data.List (sort)

groupTuples :: [(Char, String)] -> [(Char, [String])]
groupTuples tuples = [(k, sort v) | (k, v) <- grouped]
    where grouped = toList $ fromListWith (++) [(k, [v]) | (k, v) <- tuples]
```

Which works as follows:

```
*Main> groupTuples [('a', "Hello"),('b', "Goodbye"), ('a', "World"), ('b', "World")]
[('a',["Hello","World"]),('b',["Goodbye","World"])]
```